# How to treat sensitive data upon registration in Yii2

Tags: authentication, yii2

I am trying to create a user registration page in yii2. Without using any extension. I am using GII to generate Models and so on.

I need to treat the following issues:

1. Make some attributes not accessible to anyone trying to register (as the auth-key, token, permission).
2. An administrator is able to create a new user and assign him a permission, but others trying to register are not able to see or change the permision attribute.

I am waiting...

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take a look at the Role Based Access Control provided by Yii 2.  There are more details here http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html

First you will need to create the permissions and roles.  It sounds like you will need a user role and then also an admin role.  These two roles will have different permissions and you can limit a user's actions based on their role type.

This is an example of creating an admin role and 'addPermission' permission.

```
$auth = Yii::$app->authManager;

$permission = $auth->createPermission('addPermissions')
$permission->description = 'Add User Permissions';
$auth->add($permission);

$admin = $auth->createRole('admin');
$auth->add($admin);
$auth->addChild($admin, $permission);
```

Then in the controller where you allow a user to add a permission for another user you can check that they are allowed to perform that action.

```
if (\Yii::$app->user->can('addPermission')) {
    // add user permission
}
```

The page that I linked to has much more detailed information but the above will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Kelly.
Beside what you said, it is possible to create multiple scenarios in the user model. Thus we can ban any attempt to load the model with the permission attribute from a post.

It is just for more security.